# JMeter - View Result tree - Response Data is displaying HTML code but no values

Tags: controller, automation, jmeter, performance-testing

enter image description hereI am new to JMeter Load testing tool.

Below is the scenario. 
1. Login - Select a form - Fill the form.
2. On save button an "Application Number" will be generated(Useful in rest of the application.

Below are the steps that i have performed.
1. Thread Added - Transaction Controller Added - View Result tree added.
2. Script Recorded against the same and Executed.

Observations - 
1. On form save button, Application Number is getting generated but not displayed in the Response data(Got to know using Fiddler Tool)
2. Response data for all the pages is exactly same.
3. Only HTML tags and some JS/CSS scripting is displayed, but no useful information regarding Application Number is displayed.

Can i use any other controller/What is wrong with current controller?

Please Suggest/Help

Answer (score 0):

You most probably did not correlate some dynamic data after recording.

The usual process is the following:

1. Start Recording
2. Navigate doing your usual scenario
3. Find and make any ID data dynamic using PostProcessor to extract the ID and inject it using variable (${variable})

Comment: Yes. this is exact process i have followed.
further I have analyzed that the form is getting submitted in POST method... does this have any relation with result tree not displaying the data???

Comment: Can you show some screenshot of what is not shown ? Thanks